# 9 Mb Slackware distro - possible?

Tags: linux, slackware, small-distribution

Is it possible for a slackware distro to be `9 Mb` in size, have `/bin /dev /var /proc /sys` directories completely empty, and have only following content in the rest of the directories:

```
/proc
/sbin
/sys
/usr
/var
/exciter_drv.ko
/nvram_drv.ko
/bin
/boot
/dev
/etc
/lib
/lost+found
/sbin/init
/sbin/tcsd
/usr/local
/usr/local/var
/usr/local/var/lib
/usr/local/var/lib/tpm
/boot/bzImage
/boot/grub
/boot/grub/stage1
/boot/grub/menu.lst
/boot/grub/stage2
/boot/grub/default
/boot/grub/checkfile
/etc/rc.S
/etc/fstab.save
/etc/aumixrc
/etc/HOSTNAME
/etc/nsswitch.conf
/etc/passwd
/etc/rc.inet
/etc/rc.6
/etc/lilo.conf
/etc/rc.udev
/etc/mtab
/etc/inittab
/etc/rc.0
/etc/profile
/etc/random-seed
/etc/asound.state
/etc/rc.messagebus
/etc/hosts
/etc/rc.M
/etc/group
/etc/rc.init
/etc/fstab
/etc/rc.alsa
/etc/host.conf
/etc/ld.so.conf
/etc/rc.acpid
/etc/rc.K
/lib/libtspi.so
/lib/libz.so.1
/lib/libnss_files.so.2
/lib/libpthread.so.0
/lib/libgcc_s.so.1
/lib/ld-linux.so.2
/lib/libnsl.so.1
/lib/libc.so.6
/lib/libnss_compat.so.2
/lib/libdl.so.2
/lib/libcrypto.so.0
```

Note: an executable file `/sbin/init` (which executes automatically with GRUB) when executed accesses an EEPROM chip that exists on a motherboard that the OS is supposed to be run on, is it possible that this file is *downloading* the rest of the OS once executed?

How would one determine if such OS has any networking capabilities? (`Ethernet` mainly)

Additional info:

The OS resides on a CF card which is connected to a customized motherboard with no input port/device available to connect to. Therefore I am unable to supply commands through the console. I have removed the CF card and tried booting it from a normal PC which outputs the following screen and then halts:

[image]

I have also tried mounting the CF card in Ubuntu 14.04 to execute the `/sbin/init` (the only executable that seems this OS is meant to run) which outputs various errors about not being able to contact `EEPROM` and access various directories on it like: `/data/eeprom.c`, which drew me into conclusion that the OS needs additional files before its `Filesystem` can be mounted (referring to the error on the image above)

My goal, if possible, is to add libraries necessary for SSH support, create a user with administrative privileges and connect to the OS remotely. But then again, I am unsure whether these libraries (and many other things) already exist just not on the CF card but on the EEPROM chip and are somehow merged(?)/downloaded once the OS starts executing.

Apologies for my incompetence, still studying Linux.

Comment: The /proc /dev /sys directories are pseudo directories and take up no physical space. You could certainly combine /bin and /sbin... For networking capabilities, I'd check the output of ifconfig -a ...that doesn't tell you if the env supports networking but rather if it contains any network hardware (which implies networking support)

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to interface with the OS at a place where it's supposed to be run - there is simply no input device/port to connect to. All I can is remove the CF card on which this OS resides and connect it to a normal PC and boot from there, which outputs a screen I'm going to post in a minute

Comment: However, the motherboard that the CF card is attached to does have a NIC connected to it

Comment: If you are trying to examine a black box, I'd look to see if there was a connection you could use... whether it is serial or something else. I'd also connect it in a secure network environment and use a network traffic sniffer to see what network traffic is being generated. I'd also use nmap to determine what network services are available.

Comment: @Mei I am setting a LAN to sniff on network traffic as we speak.

Comment: To get down to 9MB, I think you'll have to get something based on an embedded C library (Bionic, dietlibc, uClibc, …) and BusyBox, rather than GNU libc and GNU utilities.

Comment: A late comment about all of that: it's possible, but it depends on if author has source code for software he wants to run. If he has no source code for his /sbin/init (as I can guess from this obscure setup) then he is forced to use at least GNU libc. But if he has, he can rebuild it to use with any other libc. Good news if he has, bad if he has not. As for 9M slackware - it's not required if there is source. Take then any embeddedish distro or build yourself and put to CF card, install lilo on it - and it's ready to go and explore.

Comment: @siblynx True. Although I was unsuccessful in my original task of modifying the OS as the system had TPM module and some other security measures to prevent altering key software components.

Answer (score 1):

Lately (with x86_64 etc.) I believe the answer would be "no", especially the initramfs/kernel might be bigger than that :(
, but you could still try, especially when you custom compile the kernel and throw out anything not absolutely needed :)

The error you see, are related to settings in the initramfs or grub/etc. that doesn't have the right root partition setup, or not formatted correctly for it to be mounted, not the "sparseness" of the filesystem.

NEtwork booting is something done "easily", but I'll advise you to consider first checking how it's done from UEFI etc. where things go through the ARP/DHCP -> TFTP -> NFS/iSCSI mount cycles to understand how those works before trying to do a custom method yourself.